# Docker gives 'no such file or directory: unknown' on a docker run command

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, virtualization

I was able to successfully build a Docker image, via `docker build -t foo/bar .`.
Here is its *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

COPY benchmark.sh /home/benchmarking-programming-languages/benchmark.sh
CMD [ "/home/benchmarking-programming-languages/benchmark.sh -v" ]
```

And here is the file *benchmark.sh*:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
## Nothing here, this is not a typo
```

However, running it via `docker run -it foo/bar` gives me the error:

> Error invoking remote method 'docker-run-container': Error: (HTTP code 400) unexpected - failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/home/benchmarking-programming-languages/benchmark.sh -v": stat /home/benchmarking-programming-languages/benchmark.sh -v: no such file or directory: unknown

Despite this, when running the image as a container with a shell, via `docker run -it foo/bar sh`, I can, not only see the file, but execute it with no errors!
Can someone suggest a reason for why the error happens, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [your `Dockerfile` you have specified the `CMD`](https://github.com/Mariosyian/benchmarking-programming-languages/blob/c4b430484f9c2b1adcd5a10adc90438d0ad6301b/Dockerfile#L51) as

```dockerfile
CMD [ "/home/benchmarking-programming-languages/benchmark.sh -v" ]
```

This uses the [JSON syntax of the `CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) instruction, i.e. is an array of strings where the first string is the executable and each following string is a parameter to that executable.

Since you only have a single string specified `docker` tries to invoke the executable `/home/benchmarking-programming-languages/benchmark.sh -v` - i.e. a *file* named "`benchmark.sh -v`", containing a space in its name and ending with `-v`. But what you actually intended to do was to invoke the `benchmark.sh` script with the `-v` *parameter*.

You can do this by correctly specifying the parameter(s) as separate strings:

```dockerfile
CMD ["/home/benchmarking-programming-languages/benchmark.sh", "-v"]
```

or by using the [shell syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

```dockerfile
CMD /home/benchmarking-programming-languages/benchmark.sh -v
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those syntaxes appear to be working. After changing the `Dockerfile` I delete the image and any containers and rerun using the `docker build -t` command.

After running the image with `docker run` I get this now `/bin/sh: 1: /home/benchmarking-programming-languages/benchmark.sh: not found`. Running a shell on the image now doesn't even allow me to run `./benchmark.sh`. It returns with `sh: 1: ./benchmark.sh: not found`.

Comment: So after a retry and `docker-compose up` on my laptop, this worked. I'm not sure what happened at all, but this is the fix. I thought that flags could be passed with the file name as I had them separately originally so maybe I rebuilt the image wrongly such that it skipped over some steps.