# How to run java -cp command inside docker container

Tags: java, docker

I have requirement to run Java JAR using the `java -cp` command.
When trying to run the Docker image using the `docker run` command, it's giving me the error

> no such file or directory: unknown.

My *Dockerfile*:

```bash
FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_VERSION
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /tmp
COPY xyz/xyz.jar  /tmp/xyz.jar 
COPY xyz/xyz.csv /tmp/xyz.csv
ENTRYPOINT ["java -cp /tmp/xyz.jar -Dloader.main=com.x.y.MainClass --spring.profiles.active=dev --runId=test --tasksFile=/tmp/xyz.csv "]
```

Comment: If you are using the _exec form_ for the entrypoint, each space have to be replaced by a separate string > `["java", "-cp", "/tmp/xyz.jar", "-Dloader.main=com.x.y.MainClass", "--spring.profiles.active=dev", "--runId=test", "--tasksFile=/tmp/xyz.csv"]`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Comment: Could be closed as a duplicated of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71475076/2123530

Comment: suggested change worked. Thanks!